# Why are my buttons not rendering in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-rendering

So I'm new to react and I would like   add rendering logic so that the "Update Course" and "Delete Course" buttons only display if:

- There's an authenticated user.
- And  `user._id` matches `UserId`
  here is what I have so far:

**CourseDetail**

```
    class CourseDetail extends Component {
              constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                  course: [],
                  user: [] //user state contains user data
                };

                this.handleButtonLogic = this.handleButtonLogic.bind(this);
              }

                componentDidMount() {
                  this.handleButtonLogic() {
                }


              handleButtonLogic() {
                const user = this.state; 
                const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('IsLoggedIn');
                const UserId = localStorage.getItem('UserId');
                const button = document.getElementsByName('button')
            if (!isLoggedIn && user._id !== UserId) {
             button.style.display = 'none'
            }  else {
              button.style.display = ''
            }
              }

            render() {
        const { course, user } = this.state;

        return (//JSX inside
          <div>
            <div className="actions--bar">
              <div className="bounds">
                <div className="grid-100">
                  <span>
                    <NavLink to={`/courses/${course._id}/update`} className="button">Update Course</NavLink> 
                    <NavLink to={"#"} className="button" onClick={this.handleDelete} > Delete Course</NavLink>
                  </span>
    }

export default CourseDetail;
```

this is the error I get:

[image: React Error]

can someone help?

Comment: you're trying to update the DOM in an anti pattern (because you're using React). you should use state and add / remove a classname on the button with that state variable. The class on the button element should determine the css display property

Comment: `const button = document.getElementsByName('button')`. returns html collection and also there are no buttons with `name=button`

Comment: @RobinZigmond thats not true actually, `componentDidMount` happens **after** `render`. The issue is assuming this returns a single button object `const button = document.getElementsByName('button')`... when really its a HTML Collection array. So the error really is *`array.style` is undefined*. But like you said instead of answering that its better to do this the React way :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell - thanks for the correction, I just looked it up and you are correct. I'm relatively new to React myself and am surprised by that, but I know I have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just moved your logic inside render itself, and have used ternary operator to conditionally render. If user is authenticated and user id matches the current user's id, it will display the buttons.

Closer look at ternary:

```
{(!isLoggedIn && user._id !== UserId) ? (<span>
   <NavLink to={`/courses/${course._id}/update`} className="button">Update Course</NavLink>
   <NavLink to={"#"} className="button" onClick={this.handleDelete}>
                  Delete Course</NavLink>
</span>) : null}
```

**Edited Code:**
`handleButtonLogic()` is not needed if we do the following, I have removed it too.

```
class CourseDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      course: [],
      user: [] //user state contains user data
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {course, user} = this.state;
    const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('IsLoggedIn');
    const UserId = localStorage.getItem('UserId');
    return (
      <div className="actions--bar">
        <div className="bounds">
          <div className="grid-100">
            {(!isLoggedIn && user._id !== UserId) ? (
              <span>
                <NavLink to={`/courses/${course._id}/update`} className="button">Update Course</NavLink>
                <NavLink to={"#"} className="button" onClick={this.handleDelete}>
                  Delete Course</NavLink>
              </span>
            ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CourseDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

For react, need a different mind set than modifying DOM from javascript.
Here i added logic to show/hide the button by adding the logic to have hide className or not. You could add the conditional logic to entire span as well.

```
const hide = {
  display: none  
};

class CourseDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      course: [],
      user: []
    };
  }

  handleDelete = () => {
  }

  handleUpdate = () => {
  }

  render() {
    const { course, user } = this.state;

    return (
      //JSX inside
      <div>
        <div className="actions--bar">
          <div className="bounds">
            <div className="grid-100">
              <span>
                <NavLink 
                  to={`/courses/${course._id}/update`}
                  className={'button ' + (!isLoggedin && user._id != UserId ? 'hide' : '')}
                  onClick={() => this.handleUpdate()}
                >
                    Update Course
                </NavLink> 
                <NavLink 
                  to={"#"} 
                  className={'button ' + (!isLoggedin && user._id != UserId ? 'hide' : '')}
                  onClick={() => this.handleDelete()} 
                >
                    Delete Course
                </NavLink>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CourseDetail;
```